# How to not open window

Tags: python-3.x

```
from tkinter import *

def firstPage():
    def goSecond():
        root.destroy()
        secondPage()

    root = Tk()

    text = Label(root, text="1")
    text.pack()
    btn = Button(root, text="go to 2", command=goSecond)
    btn.pack()

    root.mainloop()

def secondPage():
    def goFirst():
        root.destroy()
        firstPage()

    root = Tk()

    text = Label(root, text="2")
    text.pack()

    btn = Button(root, text="go to 1", command=goFirst)
    btn.pack()

    root.mainloop()

firstPage()
```

I made this code and I want it to open a new page, but it open a new window, I understand why but I don't know how to open a page instead of open a window.

Comment: search for a widget to hide and show like frames or notebooks ........

Comment: yes, but how can I do it?